# Recursive liftIO

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I've looked at the some instances of MonadTrans, for MaybeT the implementation looks like this:

```
instance MonadTrans MaybeT where
    lift = MaybeT . liftM Just
```

As I understand the instance for MonadIO is used to do a variable number of lifts from the inner most, a IO monad, directly to the outermost. For the MaybeT case it looks like this:

```
instance (MonadIO m) => MonadIO (MaybeT m) where
    liftIO = lift . liftIO
```

What I don't understand is how this recursive function escapes the infinite loop. What is the base case?

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps surprisingly, the definition below is *not* recursive, even if it looks such.

```
instance (MonadIO m) => MonadIO (MaybeT m) where
    liftIO = lift . liftIO
```

This is because the `liftIO` on the left hand side is the `liftIO` for the `MaybeT m` monad, while the `liftIO` on the right hand side is the `liftIO` for the `m` monad.

Hence, this simply defines `liftIO` in one monad in terms of the `liftIO` for another monad. No recursion here.

This is similar to e.g.

```
instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (a,b) where
   show (x,y) = "(" ++ show x ++ ", " ++ show y ++ ")"
```

Above, we define how to print a pair depending on how to print their components. It looks recursive, but it is not really such.

It could help visualizing this by inserting explicit type arguments, at least mentally:

```
-- pseudo-code
instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (a,b) where
   show @(a,b) (x,y) = 
      "(" ++ show @a x ++ ", " ++ show @b y ++ ")"
```

Now `show @(a,b)`, `show @a`, and `show @b` are distinct functions.

Answer (score 5):

Simple equational reasoning and rewriting definitions for some specialization can help you. Base case for `MonadIO` is `IO`. `MaybeT` is monad transformer, so lets combine `MaybeT` and `IO` in some simple example.

```
foo :: MaybeT IO String
foo = liftIO getLine
```

Now let's rewrite this function definition applying instance implementations from your question step by step.

```
foo
= liftIO {- for MaybeT -} getLine
= lift (liftIO {- for IO here -} getLine)  -- step 2
= lift (id getLine)
= lift getLine
= MaybeT (liftM Just getLine)
```

1. `getLine` has type `IO String`
2. `liftM Just getLine` has type `IO (Maybe String)`
3. `MaybeT m a` constructor needs value of type `m (Maybe a)` where `m = IO` and `a = String` in our case.

Probably hardest step to analyze is step 2. But in reality it's very easy if you remind yourself types of `liftIO :: IO a -> m a` and `lift :: Monad m => m a -> t m a`. So all work is done by type inference.